# How to host Web API with AngularJs inside Virtual Directory on IIS

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-web-api, n-tier-architecture

I am new with Web Api and using n-tier architecture. I have a simple application with AngularJs as javascript framework and using Web Api as RESTFul service. I also have *Data Access Layer*, *Business Logic Layer* and a separate layer for *Model*.Html pages are included in same project containing Api, in Pages folder.
This is my project structure:
[image]

I am trying to host the project on Local IIS. I have changed the servers option from properties of FirstApp.Web to local IIS. Html pages are being displayed fine. The page contains simple login form. Using Angularjs service I am calling the Web Api which is under *Controllers* folder.

```
this.authenticate = function (obj) {
        return $http.post('/api/Employee/Validate/', obj, {});
    }
```

But it is throwing [image]

Help me to figure out how to host the whole application on local IIS.

Comment: Does the application work when you debug in Visual Studio?

Comment: application is working fine with IIS Express but not on Local IIS.

Comment: Could you post the URL which runs on Local IIS?

Comment: It is : http://localhost/FirstApp.Web/Pages/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens if you do not host the application at root level - http://localhost/Pages/Index.html.

In my saturation, I use ASP.Net MVC **_layout.cshtml**, so I get the site's URL using `@Url.Content("~")`, and append it at the front of every Angular's requested URL.

```
// This script tags is placed inside _layout.cshtml
<script type="text/javascript">        
    window.MyApp = {
        rootPath: '@Url.Content("~")'
    };
</script>
```

### Usage

```
this.authenticate = function (obj) {
   return $http.post(window.MyApp.rootPath + 'api/Employee/Validate/', obj, {});
}
```

Comment: But I am not using `Razor` view. It is simple html page. Any work around for this?

Comment: If regular html page, you will need to place the above script inside **index.html**, and manually update rootPath like this `window.MyApp = { rootPath: '/FirstApp.Web/' };`